# Класс комплексные числа, возведение в степень C++

Tags: c++, классы

Нужно написать класс комплексных чисел. Среди функций класса должна быть так же функция возведения в степень, сделать это нормально у меня не получилось, получилось только тогда, когда я делал так, чтобы функция создавала новый класс для каждой степени числа, а это неправильно. Вобщем, подскажите, что за ошибки у меня в функции возведения в степень, и как её лучше переделать/доделать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
const char root = 251;

class Complex
{
public:
double real = 0;
double imagine = 0;

public:
double subtraction(Complex *A, Complex *B)
{
    this->real = A->real-B->real;

    this->imagine = A->imagine-B->imagine;
}

double addition(Complex *A, Complex *B)
{
    this->real = A->real+B->real;

    this->imagine = A->imagine+B->imagine;
}

void multiplication(Complex *A, Complex *B)
{
    this->real = ((A->real*B->real)-(A->imagine*B->imagine));

    this->imagine = ((A->real*B->imagine)+(A->imagine*B->real));
}


void print()
{
    cout << this->real << " " << this->imagine << "i"; 
}

void fill(double a, double b)
{
    this->real = a;
    this->imagine = b;  
}

void trigonometricRepresentation(Complex *A, int *indicator)
{
    double r = 0, angle, f;
    r = modulus(this, indicator);
    if(A->real == 0)
        angle = 90;
    else    
        angle = A->imagine/A->real;
    if(angle==0)
        f = 0;
    else if(angle==1/sqrt(3) && indicator)
        f = 30;
    else if(angle==1)
        f = 45;
    else if(angle==sqrt(3) && indicator)
        f = 60;
    if(*indicator)
        cout << root << r << "(cos" << f << "-i*sin" << f << ")" << endl;
    else if(!*indicator)
        cout << r << "(cos" << f << "-i*sin" << f << ")" << endl;



}

double modulus(Complex *A, int *indicator)
{
    double mod;
    mod = sqrt((A->real*A->real)+(A->imagine*A->imagine));
    if (fabs(mod - floor(mod)) < 1e-5)
        return sqrt((A->real*A->real)+(A->imagine*A->imagine));
    else if (fabs(mod - floor(mod)) > 1e-5)
    {
        *indicator = 1;
        return (A->real*A->real)+(A->imagine*A->imagine);
    }

}

void powerOfComplex(Complex *C, int *pow)
{

    Complex *temp = new(Complex);
    temp = C;
    int i = 0;

    this->multiplication(C, temp);
    ++i;

    for(int i = 0; i<*pow-1; ++i)
        this->multiplication(C, temp);


}

};



int main()
{
double a, b;
int indicator = 0;
Complex *A_Complex = new Complex;
Complex *B_Complex = new Complex;
Complex *C_Complex = new Complex;
cout << "Enter real and imagine part of complex number" << endl;
cin >> a >> b;
A_Complex->fill(a, b);

int pow = 3;

C_Complex->powerOfComplex(A_Complex, &pow);

C_Complex->print();

delete(A_Complex);
delete(B_Complex);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Уберите из кода всё лишнее и оставьте только то, что непосредственно относится к вопросу.

Comment: Я бы переделывал все. Начиная с передачи через указатели и с непоняток типа - что у вас возвращает та же `addition`? Почему `modulus` возвращает в одной ветке значение корня, в другой - без него? А со степенью - так вы ж каждый раз просто умножаете C на temp, а не возводите в степень...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ускорять можно много и везде, НО сначала нужно чтоб просто работал. Сначала исправить баг в умножении.

```
void multiplication(Complex *A, Complex *B)
{
    if(A == this) {
        Complex Acopy = * A ;
        multiplication(&Acopy,B);
        return ; }
    if(B == this) {
        Complex Bcopy = * B ;
        multiplication(A,&Bcopy);
        return ; }

    this->real = ((A->real*B->real)-(A->imagine*B->imagine));

    this->imagine = ((A->real*B->imagine)+(A->imagine*B->real));
}
```

В случае, если хотите умножить число и возвращать результат в один из аргументов, **imagine** будет считаться неправильно.

Простой пример возведения в степень такой:

```
void powerOfComplex(Complex *C, int *pow) {
  fill(1,0);
    int ipow = * pow ;
    while(ipow > 0){
        Complex old = * this ;
        this->multiplication(C, &old);
        -- ipow ; } }
```

Сначала записывается число 1 . Затем умножается на *C  *pow раз. Ускорить можно, но потом.

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает отлично!)

Answer (score 0):

В идеале, класс комплексных чисел должен содержать, наравне с действительной и мнимой частями, также и полярные координаты, которые следует вычислять по формулам

[image: вычисление полярных координат]

При этом

[image: Комплексная арифметика в полярных координатах]

Это позволяет пересчитывать декартовы координаты комплексного числа в полярные и обратно, а также очень просто умножать, делить, возводить комплексные числа в целую степень и извлекать корень целой степени (квадратный, кубический и т. д.).

Количество корней из комплексного числа равно степени этого корня. В соответствующий метод следует добавить в качестве входного параметра номер корня *k*.

Чтобы полярный угол не выходил за пределы (-π,π], результат следует пересчитать в декартовы координаты и обратно.